# Best way to query multiple documents with same identifiers for client, performance wise in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, performance, logic

currently I'm doing a logging system for gaming servers where I work, but I'm stuck as for the best approach to solve the following:

I have multiple documents: `inv_logs`, `trunk_logs`, etc...
They look similar but have different fields as one i.e: has `entity` and entity id's as the other has `vehicle plate` only not id's or `entity`.

Keeping in mind also that we can filter by log type & query, meaning I have to take into account that I want X results from Y only, I might be able to use `.aggregate` but I need a way to check my filters without repeating the whole code, if I only want `inv` and `trunk` then I don't need the others, I'm also quite new to MongoDB I know the basics of it this is a little more in depth, thanks in advance sorry for my broken english!

Example Models:

```
const invLogSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    name: String,
    ids: [String],
  },
  item: {
    label: String,
    name: String,
    quantity: Number,
  },
  action: String,
  receiver: {
    name: String,
    ids: [String],
  },
  timestamp: Number,
});
const InventoryLog = mongoose.model("logs", invLogSchema);
```

```
const trunkLogSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    name: String,
    ids: [String],
  },
  item: {
    label: String,
    name: String,
    quantity: Number,
  },
  action: String,
  vehicle: {
    plate: String,
  },
  timestamp: Number,
});
const TrunkLog = mongoose.model("logs_trunk", trunkLogSchema);
```

I would like to retrieve data from user.name from both of these schemas, I know it's easy and how to do it, the problem begins when I introduce filtering, such as let's say I have more 2 schemas, and only want 3 of them to be searched, that's my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some sample input data and desired results.

Comment: Done, sorry @WernfriedDomscheit